# Q-select selected value and select dropdown in Vuejs3 is not displayed correctly

Tags: select, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I make an application in vuejs3 and quasar, here i am using q-select but selected option and select arrow is not welle displayed here the display

[image: https://snipboard.io/vNGegV.jpg]

i have no specific CSS, here my component

```
<template>
  <teleport v-if="show" to="#modals">
      <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Changer le status de la commande N° {{ orderId }}</h5>
      </div>
      <form class="status-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <Comment :id_order="orderId" />
          
        <!--  <select id="state" v-model="selected">
            <option
              v-for="state in orderStates"
              :value="state.id"
              :key="state.id"
            >
              {{ state.name }}
            </option>
          </select> -->
          <q-select outlined v-model="state" name="state" :options="orderStates" label="state.name" option-value="id"
      option-label="name" fill-input use-input/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <slot name="loading" v-if="loadingState">Loading...</slot>
            <slot name="loading" v-if="!loadingState"
              >Changer le status</slot
            >
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary"
            @click="
              $emit('update:show', !show),
                $emit('update:orderDetails', []),
                $emit('update:orderId', null),
                $emit('update:selected', null)
            "
          >
            Fermer
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any idea ?

Comment: Could you also provide the js and css part. Maybe a bad effect with `<teleport>`

Comment: sorry since i changed with vuetify because i switched to nuxtjs